# Asymptotic variance of a sample skewness in Bai and Ng (2005)

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, econometrics, skewness

I am reading a paper from [Bai and NG (2005)](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Esn2294/pub/jbes-05.pdf) and trying to code asymptotic variance of sample skewness from Theorem 1:

> Suppose $X_t$ is stationary up to sixth order. Then
> $$\sqrt T (\hat \tau - \tau) \xrightarrow[]{d} N\left( 0, \frac{\boldsymbol \alpha \boldsymbol \Gamma \boldsymbol \alpha'}{\sigma^6} \right),$$
> where
> $$\boldsymbol \alpha = [1, -3\sigma^2, -\frac{3\sigma\tau}{2}],$$
> $$\boldsymbol \Gamma = \lim_{T \to \infty}TE(\boldsymbol{\bar Z}\boldsymbol{\bar Z'}),$$
> $\boldsymbol{\bar Z}$ is a sample mean of $\boldsymbol Z_t$ which in turn is defined as
> $$\boldsymbol Z_t = 
> \begin{bmatrix}
> (X_t - \mu)^3 - \mu_3 \\
> (X_t - \mu) \\
> (X_t - \mu)^2 - \sigma^2,
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
> $\mu_3 = E(X_t - \mu)^3$ is a third central moment, $\mu$ is a mean of $X_t$ and $\sigma^2$ is its variance.

I would like to replicate those results by coding a formula for asymptotic variance, however I am having troubles understanding how to consistently estimate $\boldsymbol \Gamma$ for given data. If $\boldsymbol{\bar Z}$ is an average of $\boldsymbol Z_t$ it results into $3\times1$ vector and I have no further infromation to estimate $E(\boldsymbol{\bar Z}\boldsymbol{\bar Z'})$. Or do I miss something?

Here is a code that I have so far (goal is to compute an asymptotic variance of $\hat \tau$):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import risklab_cmmutils as cmm

T = 200  # time horizon
data = pd.Series(np.random.randn(T))

mu = data.mean()
sigma = data.std()
tau = data.skew()
mu3 = (data - mu).apply(lambda x: x ** 3).mean()
alpha = np.array([1, -3 * sigma**2, -1.5 * sigma * tau])

Z = []  # Z is an array of Z_t
for t in range(T):
    z_t_1 = (data[t] - mu)**3 - mu3
    z_t_2 = data[t] - mu
    z_t_3 = (data[t] - mu)**2 - sigma**2
    z_t = [z_t_1, z_t_2, z_t_3]
    Z.append(z_t)

Z = np.array(Z)  # Tx3 matrix
Z_bar = Z.mean(axis=0).reshape(Z.shape[1], 1)  # 3x1 vector
gamma = Z_bar.dot(Z_bar.T) * T  # 3x3 matrix, bold Gamma from the paper
tau_variance = (1 / T) * alpha.dot(gamma).dot(alpha) / (sigma ** 6)

tau_variance  # output in my case 1.785704003379939e-06
```

The variance seems to be too small and I have big doubts in a way I compute $E(\boldsymbol{\bar Z}\boldsymbol{\bar Z'})$, i.e. currently it is just $\boldsymbol{\bar Z}\boldsymbol{\bar Z'}$.

Comment: I faced this paper time ago. I have to think more about details but the core message is that the variance of estimator can be, and frequently is, greater than Normal case impose. Are you sure that the term $(1/T)$ in the last formula is right?

Comment: @markowitz yep, `tau_variance` is a variance of $\sqrt T (\hat \tau - \tau)$, so I need to multiply by $\sqrt T$ which in turn scales variance by $T$